# WSO2 DSS Using LIKE in Query Without Passing Percentage mark from Query String

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

We are using WSO2 DSS and implementing an Employee search API. The service provides something like Google search where when you start typing matched results are returned.

For this we have to use LIKE clause in the SQL statement. If we try to define the query in the below way

**Method 1**

SELECT Columns 
FROM EMPTable 
WHERE FirstName LIKE ':pName%'

and try to pass only the string from the service URL it will not recognize the parameter. It will pass ":pName" to query to DB.

If we define it below way

**Method 2**

SELECT Columns FROM EMPTable WHERE FirstName LIKE :pName

and pass 'SomeText%' from the query string this works fine. The second method is a poor implementation as the percentage marks and quotation marks tends to get encoded and mess up the service calls.

**Method 3**

SELECT Columns FROM EMPTable WHERE FirstName LIKE '?%'

This method work as I want. The issue is let's say I want something like

*SELECT Columns FROM EMPTable WHERE FirstName LIKE '?%' OR LastName LIKE '?%'*

then I would have to define two input parameters and ask the service user to pass in the same input to two different parameters.

Is there any way we can implement Method 1? Or for Method 3 where we can give the same parameter two ordinals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Concat function within the SQL statement so for example CONCAT(:pName,'%')

Answer (score 0):

I usually use REPLACE function, for instance: REPLACE(:pname,'*','%'). So in URI we can use * as usual in search engines.

I think REPLACE function is in every SQL dialect